# Story Identification: 90s-00s novel with a bald female protagonist who grew up in low-gravity?

Tags: story-identification

It was a book I read in highschool where the solar system was ruled by megacorporations and the protagonist was part of an underclass living in space who were all totally bald for some reason I can't remember. I think it was relatively hard sci-fi, one of the few things I remember for sure was that their ship had a tokamak reactors and they gave a pretty thorough description of it.

Comment: Welcome to SFF:SE. We recommend having a look at the [tour](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tour), which contains helpful hints for using the site. As this is a story identification question, you can also have a look at this [guide](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/tags/story-identification/info).

Comment: Hint: We do not know when you were in high school.

Answer (score 4):

[Murphy's Gambit](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/1155100.Murphy_s_Gambit) by Syne Mitchell

> Thiadora Murphy is a "floater". Born and raised to withstand a
>   zero-gravity environment, the floaters are considered the dregs of the
>   universe -- an outcast society of space workers who have been
>   ostracized and nearly enslaved. Murphy thought she could rise above
>   her floater heritage. But then she was expelled from her military
>   academy and forced to work as a test pilot for a powerful corporation.
>   It's a job with many risks -- and questionable rewards. Because her
>   mission requires her to steal something from a rival company -- a
>   faster-than-light technology that could liberate floaters once and for
>   all....

It's listed as example of Bald Women in literature on [allthetropes.wikia.com](http://allthetropes.wikia.com/wiki/Bald_Women)

> Like all Floaters, Thiadora's head is totally bald.